# How to add basic HTTP auth in HTTPD docker container?

Tags: apache-http-server, docker, httpd

I have been able to add simple HTTP auth on a server running Apache2 as a service using this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04. How can this be done in an HTTPD docker container such as this https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd.

I do not want to use a separate container for Nginx as of now.
Thanks & Regrads

Comment: you can take look here - https://github.com/koolwithk/devops-tools/tree/main/docker/httpd-basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

using `image: php:apache-bookworm`

add below to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
-
-
-
    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
-
-
-
</VirtualHost>
```

generate htpasswd file and place it under /etc/apache2/

restart the container.